# Open Data Cube: Unable to connect to database within opendatacube Conda environment

Tags: python, postgresql, conda, data-cube

I followed the steps listed at https://cubes.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.1/install.html
and did the following:

1. Installed Python
2. Installed PostgreSQL

   ```
   ssudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
   wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
   ```
3. Installed Miniconda and created a conda datacube environment

   ```
   conda config --add channels conda-forge
   conda create --name cubeenv python=3.6 datacube
   source activate cubeenv

   datacube system check
   ```

Gives me an error stating

> psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
> Is the server running locally and accepting
> connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Problem is that PostgreSQL is accessible outside the environment but not getting connected once the environment is activated.

A screenshot of the same is attached.[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVf9u.png)